# Fixing Symfony Error with Bi-directional relationships

Tags: php, symfony

I keep getting this error:

> The field MySite\ProductBundle\Entity\Product#photo is on the inverse side of a bi-directional relationship, but the specified mappedBy association on the target-entity MySite\PhotoBundle\Entity\Photo#product does not contain the required 'inversedBy=photo' attribute.

I've tried swapping and adding inversedBy and mappedBy on both sides but I cannot get rid of this error. I've tried adding the suggested code as given in the debugger, doesn't work. Here are my mappings:

**Product.php**

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="MySite\PhotoBundle\Entity\Photo", mappedBy="product", cascade={"remove"})
 */
protected $photo;
```

**Photo.php**

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="MySite\ProductBundle\Entity\Product")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
 */
protected $product;
```

Not sure what to do.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Change your **Photo.php** to :

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="MySite\ProductBundle\Entity\Product", inversedBy="photo")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
 */
protected $product;
```

And clean cache if in prod environnement.

Answer (score 0):

**Product.php**

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="MySite\PhotoBundle\Entity\Photo", mappedBy="product", cascade={"remove"})
 */
protected $photos;
```

**Photo.php**

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="MySite\ProductBundle\Entity\Product", inversedBy="photos")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
 */
protected $product;
```